# Published Ladino version of Meam Lo'ez?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, translation, midrash

The Me'am Lo'ez (מעם לועז‎), begun by Rabbi Yaakov Culi in 1730, is a commentary to Tanakh written in Ladino. It was subsequently translated to Hebrew and translated from the Hebrew to English in a fairly popular commentary in print. Does anyone know of a modern publishing house who has printed this in/with the original Ladino? When was the last time this was printed in Ladino?

Comment: The $800 [first edition](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=ISTANBUL+1746+~+FIRST+ED.+MEAM+LOEZ+LADINO+judaica+book) on Ebay is too pricy for me

Comment: HebrewBooks has a few Ladino editions. [This one](http://hebrewbooks.org/22704), for example, is from 1864; although [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me'am_Lo'ez) says it was first published from 1730.

Comment: Ladino has been written in Hebrew and also in Latin characters (alphabets). The 1864 version b a's linked to uses Hebrew; I wonder whether any use Latin.

Comment: [Beis Eked Sefarim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37114&pgnum=305) - a bibliography of sefarim printed until 1950 - lists various editions, though the last ones (in Hebrew characters, at least) seem to have been at the end of the 1800s. R. Aryeh Kaplan, in his introduction to Bereishis, mentions an edition of most of Bereishis in Latin characters, done by a Spanish university in the 1960s; whether it was continued, I don't know.

Comment: @Alex Any idea what the university is? I can try to track it down...

Comment: @minhag: R. Kaplan's introduction is [here](http://www.tzemachdovid.org/gedolim/jo/tpersonality/meamloez.html). He says that it was done by the Ibn Tibbon Institute at the University of Granada. (That said, the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me'am_Lo'ez) on Meam Loez quotes a review that says that it is full of inaccuracies.)

Comment: In an article in ladino of the [Ottoman Turkish  Sephardic Research Center](http://www.istanbulsephardiccenter.com/index.php?mid=157%5D) says that sponsosr are needed to publish a ladino version of the Meam Loez.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the work of some amazing people, all of the Meam Loez on Chumash in (Rashi-script) Judeo-Spanish has finally been made available on Hebrew Books.

Sefer Bereshit, Shemot, Vayikra and Bamidbar are taken from the 5582/1822 Livorno edition, described by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan (zichron le bracha) as being the closest version to modern Spanish.

The team was unable to locate a copy of this version of Devarim, and so the 1870's Izmir edition was uploaded to Hebrew Books.

[BERESHIT (Livorno)](https://hebrewbooks.org/66028)

[SHEMOT (Livorno)](https://hebrewbooks.org/66029)

[VAYIKRA (Livorno)](https://hebrewbooks.org/66030)

[BAMIDBAR (Livorno)](https://hebrewbooks.org/66031)

[DEVARIM (Izmir)](https://hebrewbooks.org/66032)

Anyone interested in having hard copies of this sefer printed can order them from [Judaica on Demand](https://www.judaicaondemand.com/).

Comment: It seems they only have the title page of Devarim. https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH001790979/NLI

Comment: WOOHOO.........

Comment: I thought I was the only one excited about this! ביאנבאנידו אבורדו, @Dr.Shmuel!

Answer (score 2):

The Meam Lo'ez are 17 volumes written in 150 years, I know you mean a Ladino with Hebrew letters Meam Lo'ez, but the last time printed  in **Ladino with Latin letters** were in the 2006 by the National Authority of Ladino at Israel. The book is a recompilation of Selected text from Bereshit with its introduction, glossary and index, here the book [Daalet le-Navon](http://www.bookgallery.co.il/content/english/bookpageschema.asp?BookPageID=40197).

The cultural magazine [Aki-Yerushalayim](http://www.aki-yerushalayim.co.il/ay/080/080_14_livros.htm) wrote about the book in Ladino  (my English translation):

> But since the Ladino began to be written in Latin letters at the
>   beginning of the 20th century, and that already grew 4 generations who do
>   not know the rashi letter, few can only read this book in our days,
>   what is a sin that meam Loez is a mine of knowledge not only from
>   religious point of view, also linguistic, literary and folkloric either.
>
> There are already many years from the work to make a translation of
>   Meam Loez in Latin letters, especially for those who are studying the
>   Ladino and Judeo-Spanish literature. It is true that years ago was
>   take a first test, at the University of Granada, to make a
>   transliteration the Book of Genesis, but this was first cast with a
>   different graphic we use here, any way there are not more copies. A
>   response to the work of making a transliteration that suits the public
>   in Israel (and other countries too), was given on the initiative of a
>   group of friends of the President of the National Authority of Ladino,
>   Mr. Yitzhak Navon, on occasion of his eightieth birthday we decided to
>   honor him, publishing a transliteration in Latin letters, a selection
>   of Meam Loez Bereshit .

Maybe you can get a printed copy if you email the [National Authority of Ladino](http://www.aki-yerushalayim.co.il).